# Focus to existing tab in another pane if opening file from another pane

Tags: atom-editor

There is an annoying behavior in atom I can't find the option for.

Let's say I have two panes within one window.
One of the panes has a file open in it, and the other pane does not have that file open in it. I focus on the second pane, and I click the open file from the left nav sidebar.

Here, my Atom opens the file in the second apen, even if that same file is already open in the first pane. I want to change this behavior to focus on the tab open in any pane of the window if it is already open. How can I set or change this behavior?